# Cycles renders object deep purple

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q8PwcDzb8Y) tutorial (using blender 2.8). At around 14:15 a sphere is created and a texture with some modifiers wrapped onto it; this is what I get when following the tutorial exactly:

With Eevee:

[image]

With Cycles:

[image]

Why does Cycles forget about the nodes?

I created the shader with "All" as the output.

Tried redoing the material directly in Cycles; now the sphere is purple by default and remains so even after the texture has been added.

Comment: Looks like something went wrong when switching the render engines, since the second screenshot still shows Eevee's properties in the *Material Properties* and the render pause button is missing the 3D View. Are there any error messages on the Console (*Windows > Toggle System Console*)?

Comment: I'm redoing the objects; I couldn't seem to be able to refresh the engine (I recreated the second object's material from scratch with the output set to Cycles but once created it remained purple). Pretty damn frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate the problem: it seems to be caused by setting material output to Cycles (in the material editor) while rendering with Eevee (in the render settings). The only solution I know is to render with the same render engine as you specify in the material.

Comment: I tried this but it seems to be stuck to purple while in Cycles; the first object renders fine in Eevee. Tried recreating everything using Cycles; it fails from the start.